# Bind only new data points for performance optimization

Tags: performance, svg, d3.js

Imagine I have the following call in my code:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(data, key)
    .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path);
```

Sometime later in the code, the exact same call is made, only `data` contains some new entries. How can I bind the new data entries to new paths without redrawing the existing paths? (ie. the data elements associated with existing paths never change)

This is a performance optimization: `data` contains 10,000+ entries and less than 1% of entries are added or removed every call. As you might imagine, drawing 10,000+ paths is very ressource intensive and takes several seconds to happen (during which the whole page is unresponsive to user events).

One solution is to build an array of the difference between the old data and the new data and use `enter()` only on the new data elements. However, it's tricky to have the old `data` variable in scope at the time the second data set is provided. I assume D3 must somehow internally maintain a representation of the old data and surely we could use that.

Similarly, the same process must occur for deleted data elements (every call will have a few elements removed from `data` and the corresponding paths must be removed from the DOM without touching all the other paths). However, I imagine I can figure out this part given a solution the first part.

Comment: Are all the existing paths redrawn using enter/transition/exit join structure (http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/)?

Comment: Wait... in the code snippet you included above you're actually ONLY drawing new elements –– the elements returned by `enter()`. The only d3 action here that's concerned with any old elements is the `data()` operation, which determines what elements are new (ie entering) and what elements are updated. So it sounds like it's already doing what you want. No?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I encourage you to read about [object constancy](http://d3js.org/#enter-exit) and [joins](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/join/) in d3.

The `enter()` function you cited is not only for the new data, you can basically give the new array of data by using `selection.data(newDataArray, function(d){return d.id})`, then, `selection.enter()` will give you all **new** elements, `selection.exit()` all **deleted** elements and `selection` will give you all elements in the new dataset (old+new).

[Here](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/tutorial/bar-2.html) is a nice short tutorial too.

You might also want to have a look at the [reference documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data) about data in d3.js.

Comment: Ah, got it. So this is surprisingly very simple! Thanks.